# Is there a way to change the maximum frames per second for an Angular application?

Tags: angular, angularjs

By default, all CSS animations run in 60 frames per second, meaning HTML is rendered 60 times per second. As my app always has animations running, I would like to optimize the performance and set the target frames per second to 30 or fewer. Is there a way to change the number of maximum frames per second in the Angular app?

Answer (score 1):

This is not about javascript but about your browser. This is the one deciding the FPS. So the answer is no, you can't.

What you CAN do however, as hacky as it sounds, is use JS to manage your animations, and update with `setInterval` set to 30 / 1000 (30 frames per second).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using `steps()` in your animation call:

`bounce 1s steps(30)`

Where steps is the amount of steps to take within your animation. So in 1 second, it will take 30 steps. But I am not sure how/if this will improve performance.